# Error in curve fitting and other syntax issues

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting, linear-regression

I have a set of vector 'measured_data' containing 200 sample data which are positive floating point values. I am having a tough time to find a model which fits this data.The following code returns error in every step,i.e on commenting predict(),the next command throws another error...so nothing seems to be working.I thoroughly went through the documentation and I just cannot seem to understand what is the problem and where I am going wrong.I shall be really grateful if someone can go through the code and help in mitigating the problems.Thank you.

```
Undefined function 'predict' for input
arguments of type 'double'.

Error in Untitled (line 157)
model2_pred = predict(model2_coeff, model2_data, 1);
```

CODE

```
model1 = ar(measured_data, 2,'yw');
model2 = ar(measured_data, 5,'yw');
coeffs1 = model1.a;
model1_coeff=[coeffs1(2) coeffs1(3)]
coeffs2 = model2.a;
model2_coeff=[coeffs2(2) coeffs2(3) coeffs2(4) coeffs2(5)]
x(1) = 0.0;
x(2) = 0.0;
y(1) = 0.0;
y(2) = 0.0;

y(3) = 0.0;
y(4) = 0.0;

%Solve for Model1 by putting in the coefficient values
for i=3:200
  x(i) = coeff1(2) *x(i-1) +coeff2(3)*x(i-2) ;
end  

model1_data=x;

%Solve for Model2 by putting in the coefficient values
for i=5:200
  y(i) = coeff2(2) *y(i-1) +coeff2(3)*y(i-2) +coeff2(4)*y(i-3) +coeff2(5)*y(i-4) ;

end  
model2_data=y;


model1_pred = predict(model1_coeff, model1_data, 1);
model1_residual=model1_data-model1_pred;
model1_err = resid(model1_coeff,measured_data);  %prediction errors
model2_err = resid(model2_coeff,measured_data);
subplot(1,2,1);
plot(model1_err);
subplot(1,2,2);
plot(model2_err);

model1_mse=sqrt(mean((measured_data-model1_coeff).^2));  %Mean square error
model2_mse=sqrt(mean((measured_data-model2_coeff).^2));

compare(measured_data,model1_coeff,'g',model2_coeff,'b');
```

Comment: This means MATLAB can't find the `predict` function. Sounds to me like you don't have the System Identification Toolbox installed.

Comment: I do have the toolbox.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to get this error if you are giving the wrong type of input. For example, the standard example in the documentation works fine for me, but I can obtain the same error if I try something nonsensical like:

```
predict(1,1,1)
```

Check that:

1. The first input is an idmodel or idnlmodel object (idpoly, which you'll get from ar, is fine).
2. The second input (data) is an iddata object (timeseries).

Comment: Hi,in the command mentioned in my code model1_pred = predict(model1_coeff, model1_data, 1);
 model1_coeff are the model coefficients obtained from aryule(measured_data,model_order).The measured data is a raw time series with one vector consisting of the values. and 1 indicates the one-step prediction horizon.Do you suggest that the format of the data is incorrect?According to your answer,this syntax and command seems quite valid.

Comment: You can use "whos" to check, but from your code it looks to me like model1_coeff may be of type double, since you calculate the model (model1) but then remove the coefficients from it.

Comment: Could you kindly put the correct way of doing prediction. I am still struggling with modeling of data and I am sure I am doing it incorrectly.